# What is the fastest way to compare a text with a large number of regexp with python?

Tags: python, regex, performance

I have a list of regular expressions and I would like to match with tweets that as they arive so I can associate them with a specific account. With a small number of rules as above it goes really fast, but as soon as you increase the amount of rules, it becomes slower and slower.

```
import string, re2, datetime, time, array

rules = [
    [[1],["(?!.*ipiranga).*((?=.*posto)(?=.*petrobras).*|(?=.*petrobras)).*"]],
    [[2],["(?!.*brasil).*((?=.*posto)(?=.*petrobras).*|(?=.*petrobras)).*"]],
]

#cache compile
compilled_rules = []
for rule in rules:
    compilled_scopes.append([[rule[0][0]],[re2.compile(rule[1][0])]])

def get_rules(text):
    new_tweet = string.lower(tweet)
    for rule in compilled_rules:
        ok = 1
        if not re2.search(rule[1][0], new_tweet): ok=0
        print ok

def test():
    t0=datetime.datetime.now()
    i=0
    time.sleep(1)
    while i<1000000:
        get_rules("Acabei de ir no posto petrobras. Moro pertinho do posto brasil")
        i+=1
        t1=datetime.datetime.now()-t0
        print "test"
        print i
        print t1
        print i/t1.seconds
```

When I have tested with 550 rules, I couldn't do more then 50 reqs/s. Is there a better way for doing this? I need at least 200 reqs/s

EDIT:
after tips from Jonathan I could improve about speed 5 times just but nesting a bit my rules. See the code below:

```
scope_rules = {
    "1": {
        "termo 1" : "^(?!.*brasil)(?=.*petrobras).*",
        "termo 2" : "^(?!.*petrobras)(?=.*ipiranga).*",
        "termo 3" : "^(?!.*petrobras)(?=.*ipiranga).*",
        "termo 4" : "^(?!.*petrobras)(?=.*ipiranga).*",
        },
    "2": {
        "termo 1" : "^(?!.*ipiranga)(?=.*petrobras).*",
        "termo 2" : "^(?!.*petrobras)(?=.*ipiranga).*",
        "termo 3" : "^(?!.*brasil)(?=.*ipiranga).*",
        "termo 4" : "^(?!.*petrobras)(?=.*ipiranga).*",
        }
    }
compilled_rules = {}
for scope,rules in scope_rules.iteritems():
    compilled_rules[scope]={}
    for term,rule in rules.iteritems():
        compilled_rules[scope][term] = re.compile(rule)


def get_rules(text):
    new_tweet = string.lower(text)
    for scope,rules in compilled_rules.iteritems():
        ok = 1
        for term,rule in rules.iteritems():
            if ok==1:
                if re.search(rule, new_tweet):
                    ok=0
                    print "found in scope" + scope + " term:"+ term


def test():
    t0=datetime.datetime.now()
    i=0
    time.sleep(1)
    while i<1000000:
        get_rules("Acabei de ir no posto petrobras. Moro pertinho do posto ipiranga da lagoa")
        i+=1
        t1=datetime.datetime.now()-t0
        print "test"
        print i
        print t1
        print i/t1.seconds

cProfile.run('test()', 'testproof')
```

Comment: Would you consider running parallel threads to have, say, 4 or 8 expressions tested at the same time? See multiprocessing library (http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: I suspect that the negative lookahead isn't helping you at all. While I'm not sure about PCRE, at least one RE engine uses non-greedy matching rules there at all times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going even further I created a Cython extension to evaluate the rules and now it's blazing fast. I can do about 70 requests per second with about 3000 regex rules

## regex.pyx

```
import re2
import string as pystring

cpdef list match_rules(char *pytext, dict compilled_rules):
    cdef int ok, scope, term
    cdef list response = []
    text = pystring.lower(pytext)
    for scope, rules in compilled_rules.iteritems():
        ok = 1
        for term,rule in rules.iteritems():
            if ok==1:
                if re2.search(rule, text):
                    ok=0
                    response.append([scope,term])
    return response
```

## python code

```
import re2 as re
import datetime, time, cProfile

scope_rules = {1: {1 : "^(?!.*brasil)(?=.*petrobras).*", 2: "^(?!.*petrobras)(?=.*ipiranga).*",3 : "^(?!.*petrobras)(?=.*ipiranga).*",4 : "^(?!.*petrobras)(?=.*ipiranga).*",},2: {1 : "^(?!.*brasil)(?=.*petrobras).*", 2: "^(?!.*petrobras)(?=.*ipiranga).*",3 : "^(?!.*petrobras)(?=.*ipiranga).*",4 : "^(?!.*petrobras)(?=.*ipiranga).*",},}

compilled_rules = {}
for scope,rules in scope_rules.iteritems():
    compilled_rules[scope]={}
    for term,rule in rules.iteritems():
        compilled_rules[scope][term] = re.compile(rule)

def test():
    t0=datetime.datetime.now()
    i=0
    time.sleep(1)
    while i<1000000:
        mregex.match_rules("Acabei de ir no posto petrobras. Moro pertinho do posto brasil",compilled_rules)
        i+=1
        t1=datetime.datetime.now()-t0
        print t1
        print i/t1.seconds

cProfile.run('test()', 'testproof')
```

Comment: Yes, if you have the freedom to not use exclusively Python code : Cython is always the best answer to performance matters with Python... (To my eyes, because you can keep methods exposure code externally, unlike Boost.Python - or else - would do).

Answer (score 4):

Your rules appear to be the culprits here: Because of the two `.*`, separated by lookaheads, a very high number of permutations has to be checked for a successful match (or to exclude a match). This is further compounded by your using `re.search()` without anchors. Also, the alternation including the `posto` part is superfluous - the regex matches whether or not there's any `posto` in your string, so you might as well drop that completely.

For example, your first rule can be rewritten as

```
^(?!.*ipiranga)(?=.*petrobras)
```

without any change in results. You can further optimize it with word boundaries, if you're looking for exact words:

```
^(?!.*\bipiranga\b)(?=.*\petrobras\b)
```

---

Some measurements (using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com)):

Your first regex, applied to the string `Acabei de ir no posto petrobras. Moro pertinho do posto brasil` takes the regex engine about 4700 steps to figure out a match. If I take out the `s` in `petrobras`, it takes over 100.000 steps to determine a non-match.

Mine matches in 230 steps (and fails in 260), so you get a 20-400 times speed-up just from constructing the regex correctly.

Comment: What I wanted to achieve with my regex was something like this. 

I want to make sure the string does not have "ipiranga", has "petrobras" and may have "posto".

Comment: Yes, that's what my regex does. The `posto` part is irrelevant, isn't it?

Comment: Is this expression right "^(?!.*\bbrasil\b)(?=.*\bipiranga\b).*"?

Comment: Yes, but you need to use raw strings (`r"..."`), or the `\b` will be read as backspace characters instead of word boundaries. Also, drop the trailing `.*`, it only slows down the regex.

Comment: It seems that doing .* is faster then \b

Comment: @gawry: Really? Which two regexes are you comparing exactly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17578/discussion-between-gawry-and-tim-pietzcker)

Answer (score 0):

Besides optimizing your regex patterns themselves (which will make a huge difference), you can try [Google's RE2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/) - It's supposed to be faster than Python's standard regular expressions module.

It's done in C++, but there's [PyRE2](https://github.com/facebook/pyre2), a Python wrapper for RE2 by Facebook :)

P.S. Thanks to your question, I found [a great read](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) on regex matching!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm already using but i haven't seem much difference. Maybe my measurement is just too naive.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @Tim Pietzcker 's recommendation

if you have a lot of rules, it might make sense to try a tiered approach built off of smaller rules grouped by commonalities.

for example, both of your rules above match 'posto' and 'petrobras'.  if grouped those regexes into a list together, and then qualified a dispatch to that list, you could avoid running lots of rules that would never apply.

in pseducode....

```
# a dict of qualifier rules with list of rules 
rules = {
    "+ petrobras" : [
        "- ipiranga"
        "- brasil"
        "? posto"
    ] ,
}

for rule_qualifier in rules:
   if regex( rule_qualifier , text ):
       for rule in rule_qualifier:
           if regex( rule , text ):
               yay
```

Comment: I'm going to try that. I just don't now if the overhead with those conditional statements isn't larger then with the regexps.

Comment: the only time issue you should have is in grouping the rules when you write the code.  you could potentially cut down 500 regex into 25 groups , each controlled by a regex - so it's 25 test to start.  assuming only 2 groups match, and each group has 25 regex in it, you'd have 50 second level tests.  that would cut down 500 tests to 75.

Comment: I've tested and saw a major improvement in doing something similar. I haven't done exactly as you mentioned because I need to know which of the rules I've matched. But I've grouped rules in a way that makes more sense for my use case

Comment: great!  you should update your question with a sample so the next person knows...